# Hive truncate external table with force command not working

Tags: hive

I was able to truncate external table using force command in one environment, but in another it was not working and throwing error.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE hive_table_name FORCE
```

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:24 extraneous input 'FORCE'
>   expecting EOF near '

please help if we need to configure something

Comment: hive version 3.1.0.3.0.0.0-1634

Comment: this's weird as according to this ticket it should be available in `4.0.0` version only. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-4367